# Not able to start zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to manually start zookeeper. I run

```
# source zkServer.sh start
```

It outputs:

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

When I run `#jps`, it outputs

```
15360 QuorumPeerMain
15412 Jps
```

From what I read online, Zookeeper is the same process as `QuorumPeerMain` listed above. But then when I check its status using

```
source zkServer.sh status
```

It hangs at:

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
```

So I run

```
#source zkServer.sh status > templogs.txt
```

Running above makes terminal to flash below for a moment (I have to run this command many times to read what actually is output on terminal before it closes) and closes terminal

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config:
grep: No such file or directory
grep: No such file or directory
```

Writing to `templogs.txt` following

```
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

When I open `zookeeper.out`, I can see this output:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive-0.12.0-cdh5.0.3/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hbase-0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.3/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/spark-0.9.0-cdh/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/splicemachine/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2015-06-29 15:49:40,831 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2015-06-29 15:49:40,836 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2015-06-29 15:49:40,836 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2015-06-29 15:49:40,836 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2015-06-29 15:49:40,837 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2015-06-29 15:49:40,847 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2015-06-29 15:49:40,847 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@95] - Starting server
2015-06-29 15:49:40,896 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2015-06-29 15:49:40,896 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=ingester
2015-06-29 15:49:40,896 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_25
2015-06-29 15:49:40,896 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-06-29 15:49:40,900 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre
2015-06-29 15:49:40,901 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../build/classes:/opt
```

I omit the huge path string that follows, and give below the remaining log:

```
2015-06-29 15:49:40,902 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2015-06-29 15:49:40,902 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-06-29 15:49:40,902 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-06-29 15:49:40,903 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2015-06-29 15:49:40,903 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-06-29 15:49:40,903 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=3.17.8-200.fc20.x86_64
2015-06-29 15:49:40,903 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=root
2015-06-29 15:49:40,904 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/root
2015-06-29 15:49:40,904 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/root
2015-06-29 15:49:40,909 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@755] - tickTime set to 2000
2015-06-29 15:49:40,909 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@764] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2015-06-29 15:49:40,909 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@773] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2015-06-29 15:49:40,918 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@94] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

Is it like zookeeper stuck at obtaining bindings to port 2181?

But when I run `lsof -i:2181 -s`, it outputs:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
java    15360 root  467u  IPv6 18340028       TCP *:eforward (LISTEN)
```

The pid is that of the `QuorumPeerMain`.

Running `source zkServer.sh status` on another PC, properly gives

```
Mode: standalone
```

But on this PC, I am pretty much screwed. Can anyone help me.

Comment: `source` is a shell built-in command to load (execute) the content of the given file into your current shell, so I recommend you not to use `source` to run `zkServer.sh`. Instead, simply type `./zkServer.sh` or `./bin/zkServer.sh`.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Please share the solution if you were able to resolve it and remember it.

Comment: Sorry cant recall it now

Answer (score 2):

Have you validated that the config file is fine?

Try to run Zookeeper with the config file full path

Example: zkServer.sh start /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

Answer (score 2):

It seems some problem with the PORT binding

"binding to port `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181`"

and the problem should be resolved by adding below the host entry to the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case zookeeper 3.7.0. just need shutdown tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

In my case i not install `JAVA`

so it was not started

please download `JDK` and `install`
then try again